# using CFrameWnd SetProgressBarPosition method of the taskbar feature, with CDialog in MFC

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, mfc

`CFrameWnd` in MFC classes of visual studio 2010 and later comes with a method called `CFramWnd::SetProgressBarPosition(int pos)` which uses some features added to windows vista and later os. How could I use this feature of os in MFC Dialog application e.g. with CDialog class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CComPtr<ITaskbarList3> ptbl3;
ptbl3.CreateInstance(CLSID_TaskbarList);
if(ptbl3!=NULL)
{
    ptbl3->SetProgressState(m_hWnd, TBPF_NORMAL);
    ptbl3->SetProgressValue(m_hWnd, 100, 50);
}
```

Comment: Thanks It works, But one thing I declare the CComPtr<ITaskbarList3> ptbl3; as a class member and do the CreateInstance in OnInitDialog everything is ok but when I close the application it gives error in p->Release(); of atlcomcli.h is there anything I should do

Comment: Thanks it works, and one more question. but when i put the ptbl3.Release(); in OnClose it also works. but I dont know if i am doing the write thing. Is it ok to do so?

Comment: It is OK as long as you are releasing all STA COM objects before the message pump ends.